# Non-degenerate varieties in projective space

Tags: projective-geometry

Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n(K)$, where $K$ is an algebraic closed field, be a projective variety. $X$ is called non-degenerate if $X$ is not contained in any hyperplane. For a given variety $X$, is there any criteria to showing that $X$ is non-degenerate?

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: The choice of embedding amounts to choosing a linear system on $X$ (which will become intersections with hyperplanes via the embedding). This will be non-degenerate if the linear system has no fixed part. See chapter 2.6 of Beauville's book on surfaces (the discussion applies to general dimensions I think).

Comment: @mo-b Can you say what you know about $X$—do you know its defining ideal, a parametrization, its coordinate ring...? You want a criterion for nondegeneracy, in terms of what?

Comment: To be precise: any morphism  $u:X\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^n$  is defined by a line bundle $L$ on $X$ and a surjective homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X^{n+1}\rightarrow L$.  $\ u(X)$ is nondegenerate if and only if the induced map  $K^{n+1}\rightarrow H^0(X,L)$ is injective.

Comment: Dear @abx: Could you please give me a reference for these?

Comment: The first assertion is  completely standard, see e.g. Hartshorne, Theorem II.7.1. Once you have understood this correspondence, the second assertion is obvious.